# can we placed container view inside another container view?

Tags: swift, xcode, uistoryboard, uicontainerview

I have a screen where i was placing container view inside another container view in storyboard, but xcode was giving error **Illegal Configuration: Container Views cannot be placed in elements that are repeated at runtime**.

I have 1 controller in storyboard. this controller is having 1 container view embed with 1 tableview Controller. In that table view controller cell, i have 1 container view and trying to add another container view in that cell's container view. but i am unable to add it. so does that possible?

Comment: If you still need help with this please edit your question to include as much information as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add container view into a dynamically generated UITableViewCell,

Either you can put the container view content directly inside the table view cell or you can use UITableViewController with static cells and then you can embed a container view inside the static cells